# Is there a way without a (*)splat argument to pass multiple arguments in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec, splat

I need to write a method that takes an unknown number of arguments (hence the *splat) but that passes a `yields_with_args` spec.

The code:

```
def eval_block(*args, &block)
    raise "NO BLOCK GIVEN!" if block.nil?
       block.call(args)
end
```

The rspec:

```
it "passes the arguments into the block" do
      expect do |block|
        eval_block(1, 2, 3, &block)
      end.to yield_with_args(1, 2, 3)
    end
end
```

It works, but it yields the array that *splat creates: `[1,2,3]` vs `1,2,3`, and therefore doesn't pass the rspec. Is there another way to pass on multiple arguments through a method in Ruby?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
block.call(args)
```

with

```
block.call(*args)
```

Splat has two functions: collecting arguments to an array when in definition, and distributing an array to arguments in calls. The two are inverse operations: if you expect transparent operation (three arguments go in, three arguments go out), you should distribute what you collected.